# Changed URL in Wordpress.com site and broke website

Tags: wordpress, url

I changed both the site URL and WordPress URL in my Wordpress.com WP Admin dashboard. This was a development site, so it was under a subdirectory (i.e., domain.com/devdirectory), and both the site URL and WordPress URL pointed to the same directory. When I changed it, I stupidly changed both (i.e., domain.com/newsubdirectory) without thinking through the implications and making sure I was doing it correctly. And I know better, so it's even more thoughtless. I realize I should not have changed the WordPress URL because that was the actual directory where the files were stored. But what's done is done.

Unfortunately, this left me unable to access the site with either URL, which also means that I can't reach the WP Admin for either site, so I can't change it back. The URL settings are not available from the site dashboard nor is it possible to manage the domain for the site. I am stuck. I can't get to the underlying .php files because I don't have FTP access. Can this be fixed at all?

Comment: If you have access to the WordPress database, you can edit the siteurl and home url in the wp_options table.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not. I'm trying to reach WordPress support for help, but no luck so far.

Comment: Actually, it turns out I did have access to the database, and I was able to fix it as you said. Thanks!

Comment: I will post my comment as an answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the WordPress database, you can edit the siteurl and home url in the wp_options table.

Answer (score 0):

Junky answered this question above, but since I can't mark the comment as correct, I am reposting it here.

Using phpadmin, open the WordPress database. Click on wp_options and edit 'siteurl' and 'home' with the correct URL.

It was easy to fix, and thank you to Junky for pointing me in the right direction!